# MQTT connection does not work with JHipster generated project, but code works with a start.spring.io project

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, jhipster, mqtt

I've create a monolithic JHipster application and want to process MQTT messages from my RabbitMQ server in there.

This is the code which I used in a plain start.spring.io project (in the `SpringBootApplication` annotated main class)

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel mqttInputChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory() {
    DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
    MqttConnectOptions connectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
    connectOptions.setUserName("username");
    connectOptions.setPassword("password".toCharArray());
    String[] serverURIs = {"tcp://rabbitmqserver:1883"};
    connectOptions.setServerURIs(serverURIs);
    factory.setConnectionOptions(connectOptions);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public MessageProducer inbound() {
    MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
        new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("testMqtt", mqttClientFactory(),
            "test");
    adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
    adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
    adapter.setQos(1);
    adapter.setOutputChannel(mqttInputChannel());
    return adapter;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttInputChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    return new MessageHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            System.out.println("" + message.getPayload());
        }

    };
}
```

Inserting the same code in my JHipster generated project, that application does not start:

```
    The Class-Path manifest attribute in /home/user/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.5.5/liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.5.5/lib/snakeyaml-1.13.jar
16:45:51.073 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
16:45:51.075 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter/target/classes/]
16:45:51.076 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/home/user/jhipster-mqtt-example/target/classes/]

        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

:: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 2.0.6.RELEASE ::
:: https://www.jhipster.tech ::

2018-12-09 16:45:52.175  INFO 24384 --- [  restartedMain] o.c.JhipsterMqttExampleApp               : Starting JhipsterMqttExampleApp on user-System-Product-Name with PID 24384 (/home/user/jhipster-mqtt-example/target/classes started by user in /home/user/jhipster-mqtt-example)
2018-12-09 16:45:52.176 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] o.c.JhipsterMqttExampleApp               : Running with Spring Boot v2.0.6.RELEASE, Spring v5.0.10.RELEASE
2018-12-09 16:45:52.177  INFO 24384 --- [  restartedMain] o.c.JhipsterMqttExampleApp               : The following profiles are active: swagger,dev
2018-12-09 16:45:53.377 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] o.c.config.AsyncConfiguration            : Creating Async Task Executor
2018-12-09 16:45:53.699 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByLogin      : Initialize successful.
2018-12-09 16:45:53.714 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByEmail      : Initialize successful.
2018-12-09 16:45:53.717 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.codingspiderfox.domain.User      : Initialize successful.
2018-12-09 16:45:53.720 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.c.domain.Authority               : Initialize successful.
2018-12-09 16:45:53.723 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.c.domain.User.authorities        : Initialize successful.
2018-12-09 16:45:53.807 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] o.c.config.MetricsConfiguration          : Registering JVM gauges
2018-12-09 16:45:53.813 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] o.c.config.MetricsConfiguration          : Monitoring the datasource
2018-12-09 16:45:53.814 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] o.c.config.MetricsConfiguration          : Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
2018-12-09 16:45:54.480 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] o.c.config.LiquibaseConfiguration        : Configuring Liquibase
2018-12-09 16:45:54.554  WARN 24384 --- [mple-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
2018-12-09 16:45:55.267 DEBUG 24384 --- [mple-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase has updated your database in 712 ms
2018-12-09 16:45:55.880 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] o.codingspiderfox.config.WebConfigurer   : Registering CORS filter
2018-12-09 16:45:55.948  INFO 24384 --- [  restartedMain] o.codingspiderfox.config.WebConfigurer   : Web application configuration, using profiles: swagger
2018-12-09 16:45:55.949 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] o.codingspiderfox.config.WebConfigurer   : Initializing Metrics registries
2018-12-09 16:45:55.949 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] o.codingspiderfox.config.WebConfigurer   : Registering Metrics Filter
2018-12-09 16:45:55.950 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] o.codingspiderfox.config.WebConfigurer   : Registering Metrics Servlet
2018-12-09 16:45:55.951 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] o.codingspiderfox.config.WebConfigurer   : Initialize H2 console
2018-12-09 16:45:55.952  INFO 24384 --- [  restartedMain] o.codingspiderfox.config.WebConfigurer   : Web application fully configured
2018-12-09 16:45:56.212 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] o.c.security.jwt.TokenProvider           : Using a Base64-encoded JWT secret key
2018-12-09 16:45:57.555  WARN 24384 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
2018-12-09 16:45:57.557 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.codingspiderfox.domain.User      : Close successful.
2018-12-09 16:45:57.557 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.c.domain.Authority               : Close successful.
2018-12-09 16:45:57.557 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.c.domain.User.authorities        : Close successful.
2018-12-09 16:45:57.558 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByEmail      : Close successful.
2018-12-09 16:45:57.558 DEBUG 24384 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByLogin      : Close successful.
2018-12-09 16:45:57.560  WARN 24384 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-197]
2018-12-09 16:45:57.574 ERROR 24384 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:733)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1266)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.codingspiderfox.JhipsterMqttExampleApp.main(JhipsterMqttExampleApp.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:733)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1266)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1093)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:819)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:725)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1093)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:819)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:725)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3526)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3415)
    at java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement.isAnnotationPresent(AnnotatedElement.java:258)
    at java.lang.Class.isAnnotationPresent(Class.java:3425)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:570)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.isHandler(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:218)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690)
    ... 53 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

For reference:
The working project: https://github.com/CodingSpiderFox/spring-boot-starter-mqtt-example

The JHipster generated project I cannot make start up correctly: https://github.com/CodingSpiderFox/jhipster-mqtt-example

Comment: Oh, added the new logs

Comment: This is very likely a classpath issue, I suggest you compare the versions of dependencies between the 2 projects using `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: The main difference I found is that the working project is using spring boot 2.1.1 while my JHipster project is using 2.0.6. I don't know how to update the JHipster generated project, see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53770651/how-to-override-the-spring-boot-version-used-by-jhipster

Comment: You should go to https://start.spring.io/ and generate a project with spring boot 2.0.7 (latest 2.0 release) and rabbitmq and compare. It should be easier than upgrading to 2.1

Comment: Changed the version to 2.0.6 and it still worked so it seems that this is not the problem

Comment: Good to know. When I ran your project under debugger with a breakpoint in TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy's constructor it showed which class was missing although there were other issues. You could try to dig deeper in this direction.

Comment: Did you make sure the spring integration core dependency was added? See https://github.com/CodingSpiderFox/jhipster-mqtt-example/commit/967221aae3abf01e7781efeac77e5ae26e6c0d5b#diff-593fd63d5b8c7417101ab4f08c28857e

Comment: No I did this test the day you published your repo but I added it in my own copy too.