# How to override the spring boot version used by jhipster

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

my JHipster generated application uses

`<jhipster-dependencies.version>2.0.28</jhipster-dependencies.version>`

which includes Spring Boot v.2.0.6

But I want to use Spring Boot 2.1.1

What do I need to change in my pom.xml to achieve that. 
I tried to set `<spring-boot.version>2.1.1.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>`

But when I build & run, still v2.0.6 is used.

Comment: Even if you updated Spring Boot version, it would not be enough, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/8683

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for asking this question. The comment to your question by Gael pointed me in the right direction. I've just completed an upgrade of my legacy project. Here is how I did it:

1. Go to this link: https://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/
2. Follow the instructions for automatic upgrade ( Make sure before you upgrade that you create a new branch, there are sure to be merge conflicts).
3. Resolve the merge conflicts and run your tests.
4. Commit the changes to avoid having to repeat the work.

Above all read the instructions and understand them before beginning because otherwise you will become frustrated.

You can get the list of JHipster release versions here: https://www.jhipster.tech/releases/

Comment: is there a way other than this

Comment: there are a lot of changes when jhipster is upgraded. also if there is custom chnage in the generated classes its a headache

Comment: @GeorgeThomas No. It's known as the dark side of JHipster.

Comment: I'm doing it in vscode and it's not too bad. It's asking me if I want to keep some of my previous code in the 'source control' window.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, my jhipster version is 3.9.1 and spring boot's version is 2.2.7.RELEASE.

So to upgrade spring-boot.version to latest 2.7.5:

Add dependency management from Spring Boot before Jhipster as follow:

```
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.jhipster</groupId>
        <artifactId>jhipster-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${jhipster-dependencies.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

It worked for me